# Mootools: Call method of null

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have something like `$$('[map="true"]').addClass('hidden');`
but sometime map is not exists. Can i call methods in mootools without breaking js and not adding if condition before method call? AFAIR jQuery check this by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to use `[map="true"]` as a selector, as seems to be with `$$`, then it is a string, not a variable assignment.

```
 $$('[map=true]')
```

Comment: thx. mistake in example. but questuion is about not calling method if selector == null or array.length == 0. without if condition, ofcourse.

Comment: Then I don't really understand, since from my testing, there's no problem with using `addClass` on the result of `$$`, even if it is empty.

Comment: well, `$$().method()` will map to `$$().each(function(el) { el.method(); });`, which on a length of 0 will just exit without any iterations. so you are safe. this is actually a handy technique for referencing elements that may not be there. eg, `$("modal").destroy()` will fire an exception if it's not missing so you need to check if it's not null (`if ($("modal")) $("modal").destroy()` or, you can do `$$("#modal").destroy();` safely.